# Dynamic modification of a shapefile display in a Python simulation program

Tags: python, gis, shapefile, repast-simphony, openmap

I would like to be able to use a GIS-based shapefile in a Python simulation program in a way that its display can be dynamically changed as time progresses in the simulation (that's it, at every simulation tick, certain facets of the shapefile display/view can be changed). These dynamic changes in the shapefile display in the simulation can be, for example, the alteration of colors of the shapefile polygons, adding (writing) points, circles or pie-charts somewhere inside these polygons, or change of their colors, and similar things.

For those familiar with Java-based Repast 3, this simulation toolkit was using (integrating) Java-based OpenMap (from BBN Technologies, http://openmap-java.org/) to make what was explained above possible, as explained here (please see the figures of how this may look like):  http://repast.sourceforge.net/repast_3/how-to/Gis_How_To.html

The question is: do you know a similar toolkit/program/module in Python (or any other solution) which does the same work as OpenMap in order to do what is explained in the first paragraph above?